# How to have an Input submit value on several lines in HTML

Tags: html, css

Does anybody know if there is a way to display the text value of an  button in HTML on several lines ?

I mean, if you lock the width of the button in the associated CSS and you want the text on the button to be on 2 lines for example..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469088/html-can-i-display-button-text-in-multiple-lines/24411139#24411139

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="line &#10; break" />
```

Comment: To extend that: <input type="button" value="line &#10; break" onclick="document.FORMNAME.submit()" />

Comment: OK ! Exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Argh ... correction, this doesn't work when I try to use it with an asp:Button control and passing the Text value in the codebehind ...

Comment: Have you tried putting a linebreak direct into the string?  I'm not sure what the c# equivalent is, but in VB it would be "line " & vbCrLf & " break".

Comment: Thanks a lot robertc ! Tested and approved :)
The equivalent is : "line " + Environment.NewLine + " break"

Comment: Interesting and works well in modern browsers, but if you care about older browsers some old browsers may not understand that &#10;

Answer (score 2):

You can use the <button> element, which allows for styling (and text-wrapping).

Only problem with that is that if you have multiple button elements on the same page, you will potentially run into issues with IE6 passing name/value pairs to the server incorrectly.

Comment: Yes I used to use it but in fact the input is an asp:input element and has to stay like this. thanks !

Comment: Button styling is not very well supported, unfortunately. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (using Chrome, didn't test other browsers):

```
myButton.Text = "Click \r\n me";
```

Comment: By the way, that's C#. I assumed you're using ASP.NET since you said you use it on a asp:Button control. You can do the same thing if you're using VB instead.

Answer (score 0):

Split the text on the button by adding where you want to break the line the following sequence: `\r\n`
For example: `<input type="submit" value="Line1\r\nLine2">` will display a submit button with caption Line1 on top of the Line2.

For beginners: `\r\n` will not be displayed, but used by the browser to understand that you want to break the line; it is not necessary to leave empty spaces on the left or the right of `\r\n`