# HTML: can I display button text in multiple lines?

Tags: html, css

I have a button with long text like "Click here to start playing". I want to control the width and display the text in multiple lines. Is it possible in html/css?

Comment: Sure, just add desired `width` value to the button or `<br />` in the button text.. I think you might want to define what type your button is? If its just regular `<button>` then what I said above, would work just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/DHjXx/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here are two options:

```html
<button>multiline<br>button<br>text</button>
```

or

```html
<input type="button" value="Carriage&#13;&#10;return&#13;&#10;separators" style="text-align:center;">
```

Comment: The method with &#13;&#10; doesn't work for IE10 (works for Chrome)

Comment: @MikeKeskinov I am facing the same problem. That method is working only for chrome and <button> tag is working only for the IE10 but not chrome. Do you have any method which works for both chrome and IE10?

Comment: the css white-space property is the way to go, no need to manually stick in newlines

Answer (score 146):

Yes, you can have it on multiple lines using the white-space css property :)

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    white-space: normal;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Some long text that won't fit." />
```

add this to your element

```
 white-space: normal;
 width: 100px;
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Can I control how it is displayed? For example, I want the width is 180px, but only one word per line.

Comment: You could set the left and right padding to 90px (meaning you'd 'crush' the contents); by default it will only break words on a `-` character I believe. This will probably work fine for dynamic texts. Though if you have a static text, you might want to try using the &#13;&#10; as given in m.edmondson's answer. I updated the fiddle with both options: http://jsfiddle.net/ZbJBc/7/

Comment: I see this working well on Firefox, but not Chrome. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Hey, I just checked; but in my Chrome (dev/40) it still works correctly. Could very well be, of course, that beta or stable has a bug breaking it (wouldn't be the first time).

Comment: I replaced "100px" by "8em" for my text size, and it works in Chrome and Firefox (+1).

Answer (score 26):

This CSS might work for `<input type="button" ..`:

```
white-space: normal
```

Comment: This doesn't let you manually do it but it works where buttons might stretch beyond content area (like mobile phones).

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is, and you can also use it like this

```
<button>Click here to<br/> start playing</button>
```

if you want to make the break yourself.

Answer (score 5):

one other way to improve and style the multi-line text is

```
 <button>Click here to<br/> 
     <span style="color:red;">start playing</span>

   </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break a text using an entity in between the value. See the entity in example below:

```
<input style="width:100px;" type="button" value="Click here &#x00A; to &#x00A; start playing">
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Firefox 55.0.3. Didn't check any other browser.