# What is a good way to make a button display text over multiple lines?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function rollDice() {

    var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You rolled a " + diceRoll + "!";

  }
```

I made a button activate the function on a webpage, but after i click it a second time, it replaces the message instead of putting the words on a second line. How would I make the function put in another entry on another line?

{Example}

On first button press:

```
 You rolled a 4!
```

On second button press:

```
 You rolled a 4!

 You rolled a 5!
```

Comment: Can't you just output HTML tags that would do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469088/html-can-i-display-button-text-in-multiple-lines

Comment: document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "You rolled a " + diceRoll + "!";

  }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: can I display button text in multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469088/html-can-i-display-button-text-in-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new string to the existing value, followed by the "br" tag to start a new line.

Example:

```
function rollDice() {

  var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
  var str="You rolled a " + diceRoll + "!";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += str+"<br>"

}
```

Comment: The main thing here is the `+=` rather than `=`, not the line break tag.

Comment: Ah, meant to add that in the explanation...but the line break is also required in the question.

Comment: No prob...it's the thought that counts, anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Node#insertAdjacentHTML` instead of `Node#innerHTML` to avoid passing the same unchanged HTML to the parser repeatedly.

To make each result appear on a new line, use the `<br>` tag.

```js
const roll = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
const format = input => `You rolled a ${ input }!<br>`;
const listen = e => result.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', format(roll()));
const result = document.querySelector('div');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', listen);
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div></div>
```