# How to make bold only 1 line of submit value amongst several lines

Tags: html, css

I have input submit value in 2 lines. I referred [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343418/how-to-have-an-input-submit-value-on-several-lines-in-html) and was able to get input value in 2 lines. Now i want is to make text bold only for 1 line.

For eg: Input value text is shown as

```
line 1
line 2
```

I want to make only **line 2** as bold.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why not use an anchor and put some spans inside and then simply style the anchor as you want? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8LMCe/1)

Comment: This isnt possible for `input` elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use a button tag instead:

```
<button name="test">line 1<br /><strong>line 2</strong></button>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zeLB5/)